# Patch SUPEE 6285 v2 Error Line 907

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6285

I'm attempting to patch SUPEE 6285v2. I have successfully applied the other patches prior to it and 6285v1. I reverted v1 and tried to apply v2, and received this error.

```
can't find file to patch at input line 907
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 7bceece..88753c3 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`
```

This is a custom template and there is no cart.phtml in that directory. I went ahead and copied the cart.phtml from the modern template to that directory, then I received this error:

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 115.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml.rej
```

I checked and it did not save a reject file. Unsure of how to proceed at this point. I'm running magento version 1.9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

if `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml` doesn'T exist, get it: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Or even better, reinstall your magento. If this file is missing ,there are more missing files.

Comment: I downloaded this cart.phtml and now I receive this:
`patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml.rej`

Comment: I think I linked the wrong version :) You need https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.0.1/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml